# Regex Replacement lookhead

Tags: java, regex

I am not able to do a replacement regex

for example I have the email

felipe@gmail.com

and I want to replace

```
f****e@g***l.com
```

I already got the start

```
(?<=.).(?=[^@]*?.@)|(?<=\@.).
```

Below a link from where I am testing

[REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/bFP9bs/1)

Comment: Felipe - just be careful with the regex answers below as if you use a domain such as `.co.uk`, you may not get the desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a bit of further tweaking on the pattern, you could achieve that:

```
"felipe@gmail.com".replaceAll("(?<=[^@])[^@](?=[^@]*?.[@.])", "*");
```

This will give you `f****e@g***l.com`.

A possibly more efficient, and more readable solution might be finding the indexes of `@` and `.`,
and putting together the desired result from substrings:

```
int atIndex = email.indexOf('@');
int dotIndex = email.indexOf('.');
if (atIndex > 2 && dotIndex > atIndex + 2) {
  String masked = email.charAt(0)
    + email.substring(1, atIndex - 1).replaceAll(".", "*")
    + email.substring(atIndex - 1, atIndex + 2)
    + email.substring(atIndex + 2, dotIndex - 1).replaceAll(".", "*")
    + email.substring(dotIndex - 1);
  System.out.println(masked);
}
```

Comment: tks but
almost this, for example
felipe@myhost.com.br
doens't work

Comment: I'm going to use java, no regex, tks

Comment: @FelipeFlores That specific example will work with my answer below, although probably all answers will have their own flaws considering the intricacies of email addresses.

Answer (score 3):

I found this: `(?<=.)([^@])(?!@)(?=.*@)|(?<!@)([^@])(?!.*@)(?!\.)(?=.*\.)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bFP9bs/2)

Answer (score 2):

You can use pattern like this :

```
String str = "felipe@gmail.com";
String regex = "(.)(.*?)(.@.)(.*?)(.\\..*)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
String result = "";
if (matcher.find()) {
    result = matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(2).replaceAll(".", "*")
            + matcher.group(3) + matcher.group(4).replaceAll(".", "*")
            + matcher.group(5);
}

System.out.println(result);// output = f****e@g***l.com
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach is to use `StringBuilder` and avoid regex at all.

The answer's above *may* not work if there's an `@` in the email name, or if the domain is something like `.co.uk`

So this may help in those scenarios:

```
        String email = "felipe@gmail.com";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(email);
        int mp = sb.lastIndexOf("@");
        int dp = sb.substring(mp).indexOf(".");
        for (int i = 1; i < sb.length(); i++) {
            if (i != mp && i != mp - 1 && i != mp + 1 && i != ((mp + dp) - 1) && i < (dp + mp)) {
                sb.setCharAt(i, '*');
            }
        }
```

Of course there are situations were this won't work either (i.e. an `@` in the domain), and the code is a little messy, but it may come in useful at some stage.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/pmxP1S)

Answer (score 1):

Pattern:

```
^(.)[^@]*([^@])@(.).*(.)\.([a-z]+)$
```

Replacement:

```
\1***\2@\3***\4.\5
```

Limit: Doesn't work with one-character user names and one-character domain names, e.g. *I@home.com* or *john@B.com*.